# Fedora updates - via dnf or gnome-software?

Tags: updates, fedora, yum, gnome, dnf

I'm running Fedora Workstation 22 on my Notebook. After installing it, I've done

```
dnf upgrade
```

to update all packages (was around 700 MB) - and checked the Gnome-Software applications for Updates. Gnome Software hasn't offered any updates. But sometimes, I get a notification from Gnome software to restart my Computer and install the Updates.

I found this procedure - Offline updating for libraries and components which are currently running - in the Wiki. But I don't understand how this works. If I install dnf upgrade, didn't this command update all packages to the most current version in the repos? Is Gnome-Software using different repositories, or how does this mechanism work?

I wanted to update my entire system via command-line. How can I do than? I'm a bit confused, because - for example - on Debian I could simply type

```
apt-get update && apt-get upgrade
```

to update my entire system. How is this possible in Fedora?

Answer (score 0):

Its pretty much easy to update your fedora 22.
Use this command and it will simply update your fedora 22 with all available packages.

```
sudo dnf update
```

and if you are already root, simply use

```
dnf update
```

and will update your fedora.

For any other query related to update, write it in comments.